# Do followers benefit from set bonuses?

Tags: diablo-iii

Pretty straightforward.  If I equip my follower with set items, will he/she gain the set bonuses for multiple set pieces?

Comment: I don't have any set pieces to test with, but I would suggest using one that increases an attribute when 2 or more pieces are together and see if the stats are indeed increased. Remember that the followers benefit from a times-2 bonus for main stats from objects (vitality, intelligence, strength and dexterity) so a +100 to vit will result in a +200 to vit for followers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A follower cannot activate a set bonus for themselves yet. Check out the recent [blue post here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6794833022#6) by Vaeflare.

> As it stands currently, in order to receive the benefits of set
> bonuses, the set items need to be equipped on your main character. Set
> items equipped on Followers will not contribute to set bonuses.
>
> We’re aware that this isn’t ideal, and we’re looking into some possibilities that would make using set items on Followers a more appealing choice in the future.